# How can I generate embeddings using previously generated BERT embeddings and feed them to an RNN?

Tags: python, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I'm using an **unlabeled** news corpus to fine-tune a multi-lingual BERT model. After that I'm using those embeddings to generate embeddings for words present in a new **labeled** dataset. These new embeddings will be fed to an RNN as initial weights. I want to save the embeddings of all words in the **labeled** dataset in a matrix. The number of rows in the matrix is the number of unique words in the **labeled** dataset and the number of the columns of the matrix is the dimension of the embedding vector. How can I do that?

I've shared a similar code for generating the embedding matrix for word2vec model:

```
MAX_NB_WORDS = 200000
embed_dim = embedding_size
words_not_found = []
nb_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index)) 
embedding_matrix = np.random.rand(nb_words+1, embed_dim) #no. of unique words in the labeled data=nb_words+1

    for word, i in word_index.items(): #word_index contains the indices of the word tokens in labeled data
        if i >= nb_words:
            continue
        #print(word)
    
        if embeddings_index.wv.__contains__(word): #embeddings_index contains the indices of the words and corresponding embeddings in the unlabeled data
    
            embedding_vector = embeddings_index.wv[word]
        
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
        else:
            words_not_found.append(word)
```

Plz help me to convert the same code for a multi-lingual BERT model.

**EDIT**

After going through @**noe** 's comment I'm not sure that it can be achieved at all. So, I reframed my question. Answer to any one of the questions will help me. New question is given below.

I'm using an **unlabeled** news corpus to fine-tune a multi-lingual BERT model. After that I want to use those embeddings to generate embeddings for words present in a new **labeled** dataset. These new embeddings will be fed to an RNN. How can I achieve that?

I'm just a rookie. Plz share some code snippets.

Comment: Note that, unlike word2vec, BERT does not give you word vectors but **subword** vectors. You can check [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/85570/14675) and [this other answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/85524/14675) and [yet another one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/102110/14675) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: @noe thanks a lot. I understood the diff and edited my question. Cud you plz help me by sharing some code snippets?

Comment: Also, consider that, unlike word2vec which is context-agnostic, the benefit of BERT is generating contextual representations. That is, the representations generated for a token in sentence A are different from those for the same token in sentence B. How are you planning to take that into account in your setting?